# Mysql order by with decimal and character

Tags: mysql

I've a table with the below rows.

| id | clause_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.8 |
| 2 | 5.9 |
| 3 | 5.1.1 |
| 4 | 5.10.2 |
| 5 | 5.1 |
| 6 | 5.10.2 |
| 7 | 5.4.3.2 |
| 8 | 5.40.3.2 |
| 9 | 5.6.3.2 |
| 10 | 5.40.3.3 |
| 11 | K.8 |
| 12 | L.26 |
| 13 | K.3.2 |
| 14 | Annex F |

I'd like to display it in the below format:

| id | clause_no |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5.1 |
| 3 | 5.1.1 |
| 7 | 5.4.3.2 |
| 9 | 5.6.3.2 |
| 1 | 5.8 |
| 2 | 5.9 |
| 4 | 5.10.2 |
| 6 | 5.10.2 |
| 8 | 5.40.3.2 |
| 10 | 5.40.3.3 |
| 14 | Annex F |
| 13 | K.3.2 |
| 11 | K.8 |
| 12 | L.26 |

I tried the order by, but it's not working as expected. PFB the db-fiddle link:

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pvt1rProoqjJEqhT3chQrG/8)

Comment: And where is "floating number" mentioned in subj? PS. Does your MySQL version is really 5.7.x?

Comment: Can we make any assumptions about how many levels deep the `clause_no` be nested?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Maximum of 6 dots

Comment: @Akina In my local, it's showing 10.4.21-MariaDB. In live, it is 5.7.23-23.

Comment: Simple solution applicable to local version won't work on live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may "normalize" your `clause_no` values. The solution applicable to your *In live, it is 5.7.23-23.* version.

```sql
SELECT id, clause_no
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
      UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) numbers 
    ON LENGTH(clause_no) - LENGTH(REPLACE(clause_no, '.', '')) >= num - 1
GROUP BY id, clause_no
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clause_no, '.', num), '.', -1), 8, 0) ORDER BY num SEPARATOR '');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d4ce86391c7bc8a630b79fd4673abdf9

The query assumes:

1. Max. amount of groups in `clause_no` is 6. May be increased by according subquery expand.
2. The value of a component contains not more than 8 digits. May be adjusted by changing according LPAD parameter.

---

> There is one more possibility, I forget to add in the data. Updated the fiddle. Few Characters also will be there(eg: K.8), those characters need to display last after all the number sorting. – Hello

```sql
SELECT id, clause_no
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
      UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) numbers 
    ON LENGTH(clause_no) - LENGTH(REPLACE(clause_no, '.', '')) >= num - 1
GROUP BY id, clause_no
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clause_no, '.', num), '.', -1) REGEXP '[^0-9]'
                           THEN RPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clause_no, '.', num), '.', -1), 8, 0) 
                           ELSE LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clause_no, '.', num), '.', -1), 8, 0) 
                           END ORDER BY num SEPARATOR '');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=270e63d7823ed6076b033061e7da33ba

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is one more possibility, I forget to add in the data. Updated the fiddle.  Few Characters also will be there(eg: K.8), those characters need to display last after all the number sorting.

Comment: @Hello *Updated the fiddle.* You must update the question itself! and update the link to the fiddle. *Few Characters also will be there(eg: K.8)* `1K.8`? `2K3.8`?

Comment: No, it'll start with characters. I've updated the question, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In the second fiddle link, the number sorting got affected, 5.10.2 is showing before 5.4.3.2

Comment: @Hello Incorrect regex... Fixed.

Comment: Will this affect the performance of the query result?

Comment: @Hello The performance of this query is poor anycase... of course more calculations means less performance, but these variants don't differ much.

Answer (score 1):

well, I think you have to split that `clause_no` column, which must be a string column (not a float...). Need to make sure they sort as numbers so '10' > '5'..

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(clause_no,'.0'),'.',1) AS UNSIGNED), 
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(clause_no,'.0'),'.',2),'.',-1) AS UNSIGNED), 
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(clause_no,'.0'),'.',3),'.',-1) AS UNSIGNED),
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(clause_no,'.0'),'.',4),'.',-1) AS UNSIGNED),
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(clause_no,'.0'),'.',5),'.',-1) AS UNSIGNED),
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(clause_no,'.0'),'.',6),'.',-1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: *Really only needs a single ".0" appended* The absence of a value like `'1.1.0'` does not guarantee that such value cannot exist in real data. But if the table structure contains according constraint then you're right.

Comment: so, `1.1` and `1.1.0` would sort the same and randomly one before the other. You could have `LENGTH(clause_no)` as the last sort column

Comment: but putting more ".0" at the end wouldn't solve anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is one more possibility, I forget to add in the data. Updated the db fiddle. Few Characters also will be there in clause_no(eg: K.8), those characters need to display last after all the number sorting. –

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM clause_no ORDER BY INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(clause_no,'.0.0.0'),'.',4))
```

but it'll work only up to 3 decimal points. This is because this isn't the intended purpose of `INET_ATON` function but it fits well here.

Comment: nice idea, except he has 6 fields or maybe 7

Comment: Yaa, Thanks, updated the answer mentioning this.

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal Thanks for the answer. There is one more possibility, I forget to add in the data. Updated the db fiddle. Few Characters also will be there in clause_no(eg: K.8), those characters need to display last after all the number sorting.